# Разница использования библиотек поддержки?

Tags: java, android, lib, android-support-library, android-library

При чтении статей сталкиваюсь с тем, что пишут нужно подключить такую или такую библиотеку поддержки. Я немного почитал, чтоб постараться от сего зависит какую библиотеку нужно подключать.

Я так понял, что в зависимости для какого апи пишешь то такую библиотеку и нужно использовать.

Я открыл один из своих проектов и в градле заметил, что у меня бывает даже есть 2 библиотеки разных версий. Допустим так

```
android.support.v4
android.support.v13
```

Я так понимаю, что

```
android.support.v4
```

Можно вовсе удалить так как

```
android.support.v13
```

должна включать в себя все из предыдущей библиотеки, верно я понял?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

К сожалению все неправильно.

Во первых, версией библиотеки считается трехзначный номер в конце (как 24.3.0), а не число, что идет после *v.* в названии библиотеки. Эти числа - это до какого минимального API эта библиотека поддержки собственно оказывает поддержку. Так, *v.4* значит, что библиотека поддержки будет работать на устройствах с API4 и выше.

Использовать нужно версию библиотеки **не менее** чем `minSDKversion` проекта и **равную или более**, чем `compileSDKversion` (`targetSDKversion`) а крайне  желательно - последнюю стабильную (сейчас это 24.3.0), так как с каждой новой версией вносятся фиксы в существующие классы и дополняются новые классы или методы. При этом смотреть соответствие API нужно по мажорному номеру библиотеки (здесь **24**.3.0 - для `compileSDKversion` API24).

Ознакомиться с изменениями, вносимыми в библиотеки поддержки с каждой новой ревизией можно на официальном сайте разработчика Android - [здесь указано](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html), какие именно изменения и дополнения были внесены с каждой ревизией и в какие именно из библиотек поддержки (так в ревизии 24.3.0 были внесены изменения в библиотеки *v4*, *v7* (в подбиблиотеки *AppCompat*, *MediaRouter*, *Preferences*, *RecyclerView*) , *Design*.

библиотеки *support.v4* , *support.v7* и тд - это разные библиотеки, с различными классами поддержки и выполняемыми функциями и они не взаимозаменяют друг друга по принципу большей версии. С [полным списком](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html) библиотек поддержки Google и их назначением и функциями вы можете ознакомиться на все том же официальном сайте разработчика Android.

Например, библиотека *com.android.support:support-v4:24.3.0* - библиотека поддержки с минимальным API, на котором она работает API4 и версией самой библиотеки - 24.3.0. Список классов и функций этой библиотеки можно посмотреть [здесь](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v4). Как видите, это совсем не то же, что библиотека [*com.android.support:support-v7*](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v7), в которую входит вообще несколько отдельных библиотек, как *ApppCompat*, *CardView* и тд.

PS: никакой библиотеки support.v21 у Google не наблюдается ..